# How to do a terraform module of data sources?

Tags: terraform

I want to do a module of data sources, but I am unsure how to declare them? The different accounts are gonna use the same, and they are already in place.

the data sources are regarding iam and policies. 
I know usually you do :

```
module "iam" {
source = "folder"
name = "blabla"
... }
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you expand the question to show more fully what you're trying to do? It's not clear what's wrong with what you're doing right now.

Comment: @ ydaetskcoR I have a set of IAM roles and policies i am going to use in my terraform. Because all the environments have the same, and I am not allowed to touch these, I am using data sources. I can either do a module or just stick the data sources in both my account folder, so my ressources (as the cluster) can go freely get the IAM role. Hope this makes more sense?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an own *'environment'* for that. Let's name it `general`.

If you assign an own *backend* for it and configure it to use an *S3 bucket* as remote storage (recommended anyways if you work with multiple contributors), you can work with `terraform_remote_state`. 
Just import the state of `general` into your environment with

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "general" {
    backend = "s3"

    config {
        region = "..."   # e.g. "eu-central-1"
        bucket = "..."   # the remote-storage bucket name of 'general'
        key    = "..."   # e.g. "environments/general/terraform.tfstate" (as defined in the 'general' backend!
  }
}
```

You can then access the resources from that state with `ami = "${data.terraform_remote_state.general.ami}"` if you declared them as *output variable*:

```
output "ami" {
    description = "The ID of the default EC2 AMI"
    value       = "${var.ami}" 
}
```

Of course you can also output resource attributes:

```
output "vpc_id" {
    description = "The ID of the created VPC"
    value       = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
}
```